# Unable to use Musical Instrument in Character Builder

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-4e-character-builder

I'm relatively new to D&D so I find that I rely on the offline Character Builder quite a bit in order to make sure that I'm not fudging any numbers. It seems to work really well overall, but I ran into a problem when I wanted to use a musical instrument (Fochlucan bandore) as an implement for my Bard. I can purchase the item, but I can't equip it, and on my character sheet it isn't listed on the power cards.

Does anyone know why this might be? Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange... I tried and found, bought and equipped the item quite straightforwardly. The item is two-handed, but if you select it in you primary hand the Character Builder automatically un-equips your shield.

Its bonus is counted in the power preview (the frame on the right) and in power cards too.

---

**Edit:** Sorry. I just read you are using the offline version. That version has been put out-of-date before they implemented the musical instruments as implements (pun intended).